# Updating database using python and sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I'm working with a tabase server for the very first time.
And I have some psv files, which I use to update the database. I needed to change a value in every row in a table, getting the new value from a psv file. I was able to do it, but my solution is extremely slow. Here's my code

```
query = db.select([table])
ResultProxy = connection.execute(query)
ResultSet = ResultProxy.fetchall()

for row in ResultSet :
    testNum = row['num']
    rowDF = testDF[testDF['TSTNO'] == testNum] #testDF is DataFrame representation of a psv file
    newData = rowDF[' TSTCFND'].iloc[0]

    try :
        query = db.update(table).values(test_type = newData)
        query = query.where(table.columns.num == testNum)
        results = connection.execute(query)
    except :
        query = db.update(table).values(test_type = "unknown")
        query = query.where(table.columns.num == testNum)
        results = connection.execute(query)
```

I was wondering if there is a better and faster way to do this. I couldn't find much online.

Comment: It looks like you fetch some data from the database and then use it to perform updates against the same server. Try performing the entire operation in the database.

Comment: Is your table.columns.num indexed (I am guessing it should be a primary key)? Also, keep in mind that changing rows one by one will always be slow. I don't know how to tell if it is slower that it should be though.